# what is the difference between framework and bundle in iphone OS?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, bundles

what is the difference between framework and bundle in iphone OS?

Answer (score 4):

Frameworks are groups of libraries, headers, et. al. which together make up a unit that you can use when programming. Kind of like a DLL on other platforms, except more than that.

A bundle is a structured folder which contains code and other support files. Frameworks *are* bundles. So are applications.

These are the same as on Mac OS X, since the iPhone OS *is* Mac OS X (though a special version of it).

See:  [Bundle Structures](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html)

And: [Frameworks](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Framework.html)

Comment: @rrmmnn They work for me (surprising since they're seven years old). Maybe try again?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't have believed it if I hadn't tried it, but it seems that you're right. Odd behavior indeed.